# Datepicker for birthday textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a datepicker on my form that has Birthday label on it and textbox,
Now my problem is, Is there a way to prevent the user pick the current 
date today, for example the user can't choose today's date, tommorow or yesterday as his birthday. hope you can help me, Thanks :)

here is my sample code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="md-form">
 <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control " placeholder="Birthday" style="margin-top:-30px" name="date1" required>

</div>
```

here is my sample javascript:

```
<script>
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
   showOtherMonths: true
    });
</script>
```

i know this is not enough script, im beginner at javascript and jquery but hope you can help me.Im using Bootstrap jQuery DatePicker material design

Comment: All the answers are good but you need to validate on the server as well. Just a friendly reminder :p

Comment: Are you using the **Bootstrap jQuery DatePicker** or **jQuery UI DatePicker**?

Comment: im using Bootstrap jQuery DatePicker material design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery datepicker has a [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) option that you can set.

If you pass it a number, that will set the maximum date to that number of *days* from today.

**Can't choose today, nor any dates after:**

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    maxDate: -1   //The maximum date is 1 day ago
});
```

---

**Can't choose yesterday, nor any dates after:**

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    maxDate: -2   //The maximum date is 2 days ago
});
```

---

**Can't choose any dates within the past year, nor any dates after:**

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    maxDate: '-1y' //The maximum date is 1 year ago
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maxDate` for this purpose like:

```
maxDate: '-2d'  // here d is the no of days ago, you can pass any no of days that you want to restrict
```

Ex:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        maxDate: '-2d'
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc8MK/325/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your javascript

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
startDate: '-3d'
});
```

use startDate to change values according to your need and here -3 means 3 days before and 'd' basically represents day

```
startDate: '-3d'
```